# What is causing this crazy shadows?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, cross-browser

I'm doing som cross browser fixes for IE8 and I came across something I've never seen before. Is there someone who have seen this crazy shadows before? and is there someone who knows what possibly is causing this?

I'm attaching two screenshots, one from IE8 and one from Chrome.

IE8 - http://cl.ly/image/1u0t0A2D0p0l
Chrome - http://cl.ly/image/411L1B0Y2X3Y

Thanks for any kind of help!

View HTML and CSS here: http://marcusfriberg.com/skillbird/stof.html

Comment: Please provide the CSS code of the shadow elements.

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS for those elements.

Comment: You can view HTML and CSS here: http://marcusfriberg.com/skillbird/stof.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is not only happening in IE8 but also in IE9. When I checked through Developer tool, It is clearly showing that it is happening because of the property `filter` which is given in the `post-top` and `stats-type` classes. I suggest you to go with **conditional css** to overcome this problem.  Have a look at this [**link**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ie/ms530752%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)(*community additions too*) for clear understanding about the behaviour of `filter` in IE browsers.

**EDIT**:

And also in MDN, The `filter` property is not documented for IE browsers. [Check compatibility section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/filter#Browser_compatibility). It also stated that

> Older versions (4.0 through 9.0) of the Windows Internet Explorer browser supported a non-standard "filter" that has since been deprecated.

The other `filter` property which is compatible with IE Browsers can be found at this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532853%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (not for IE9).

Comment: Pretty sure I answered this! Oh well. Glad you got it sorted anyway.

Comment: @MichaelGiovanniPumo heh, yes you did. The difference is that you explained the problem and I pointed out the problem. :D (The OP linked the html file later)

Comment: @Mr_Green Ahh I see. Yep, when I answered, there was no link given. I had to make an answer on an assumption. My fault I guess! Credit to you :)

Comment: BTW, +1 for good explanation :). (It doesn't mean you should also give me +1 though.)

Comment: @Mr_Green +1 to you! :) Have a nice day.

Comment: @MichaelGiovanniPumo same for you :)

Answer (score 1):

IE8 does not support `text-shadow` in CSS, which is what Chrome and IE appear to be using here.

http://caniuse.com/css-textshadow

If this is code you inherited, then it is quite likely that someone tried to use an alternative method for IE which went horribly wrong.

There are a number of fallback ideas for IE, but one popular one is to use 'IE Filters'.

Sometimes these propriety IE filters can achieve similar effects as the standard CSS, but at other times, they need fine-tuning.

You might want to scan your CSS file for the use of filters and make adjustments as needed. Code would look something similar to:

```
#element {  
    filter: alpha(opacity=70); /* the opacity won't work! */  
    filter: glow(color=black,strength=5);  
}
```

See this article for more:

http://www.impressivewebs.com/css3-text-shadow-ie/

To achieve a better effect of text-shadow in IE, I use CSS Pie. It's amazing. Check it out here:

http://css3pie.com/

And it's even being used right now on one of my client's website: http://www.tokheim.com

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

As of this [website](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-text-shadow/):

```
p { text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000, 3px 3px 5px blue; }
```

"The first value specifies the horizontal distance and the second specifies the vertical distance of the shadow. The third value specifies the blur radius and the last value describes the color of the shadow."

It means your filter value for Y axis is too big.